# While using a custom header with react navigation for a react native app, I can't identify where this background is coming from?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation, ios-simulator

I am using the default stack from react navigation, and in my navigator screen options I have my own custom header `header: (props) => <Header props={props} />`. In my screen, I have a background colour, and in my SafeAreaView I have a background colour. For illustration I have set them both to the same.

In my custom header I am applying margin of 15 horizontally as well as to the top. So it is the colour underneath the custom header.

My question is this: Where is this header background colour being set? (the light grey one)
[Here you can see what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcIPo.png)

I have tried `headerStyle {backgroundColor}`, but no difference (i believe because using `header` overrides a lot of these options? Unsure though as it is not stated in the documentation.)

For reference, I am basing it off of this documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#options

However it appears that this background colour is being set somewhere else entirely? And so I'm not sure where.

I realize setting headerTransparent and applying margin for each screen is a viable solution but I figure there is a better way to simply set the background colour of this space correctly.

edit with header component:

```
export default function Header({ props }) {
    const { navigation, route, options, back } = props;
    const title = getHeaderTitle(options, route.name);

    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {back && (
                    <IconButton
                        type="ion"
                        name="chevron-back"
                        size={26}
                        iconStyle={styles.backButton}
                        onPress={navigation.goBack}
                    />
                )}
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: screenWidth - 30,
        height: 60,
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 15,
        marginTop: 15,
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        alignSelf: "center",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    backButton: {
        zIndex: 1,
    },
    title: {
        flex: 1,
        textAlign: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        // marginLeft: -26,
    },
    header: {
        backgroundColor: colors.neutral95,
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code from your header component?

Comment: @Abe added! Not sure if it'll be much though since issue would persist regardless of what component is used as it appears to be an issue with react navigation.